Modelling a skewed response variable
I have a biomarker ratio (amyloid 42/40) and I am having issues modelling it. This is the proportion of a biomarker to another biomarker and it is important in diagnosing dementia. I am using as both an exposure and an outcome but obviously, this distribution of the variable is more problematic when I am looking at the variable as an outcome. I would appreciate any suggestions as to what modelling approaches you have used with such data. These are the residual plots for a Gamma log link model.



Please edit the question to provide more information about your data and what questions you are trying to answer. Explain the original data that went into constructing this ratio; it's often better to work with the original data than to convert to a ratio for analysis. Regardless, the distribution of values doesn't matter much at all for a predictor variable, and a skewed distribution of an outcome variable isn't a problem provided that there is corresponding skew in predictors. The more information you can provide in the question, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

What problems are you concerned about?

Non-normality, outliers, if the models I am using are best for the data.

The proportional odds model is a great option for modeling an ordinal or continuous outcome that may be non-normally distributed, skewed, or contain outliers.
Tons of great resources on the PO model here: https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/
The Wilcoxon test is great for comparing such an outcome between 2 groups, and the PO model can be thought of as an extension of the Wilcoxon test that allows you to adjust for covariates.

If You Like the Wilcoxon Test You Must Like the Proportional Odds Model
Equivalence of Wilcoxon Statistic and Proportional Odds Model

